# How to analyse data from experiment?

Tags: anova, categorical-data

I have a problem to choose a method for analysing data from my experiment. I have one within-subjects (all four stimuli presented to every subject four times) and four between-subjects factors and a categorical dependent variable (four possible responses).

Also, I want to ask is it ok to use Chi square to test for gender differences in dependent variable since I have more males and females in groups because data are in long format and I have more than one row for every subject? I am using R and long format of data for the first time, so I am not sure how to test between-subjects factor effect with multiple rows for every subject.

[image: data_example]

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataframe so it makes it easier to see what kind of data you have and answer your question.